# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':library']

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have imported a cordova project to Android Studio 3.0 but I'm not able to test it in an AVD. The title is the error I'm get when i try to sync my project and after reading several post here, these are the steps i have taken so far

1. Gradle version = 4.3.1
2. Android Plugin version = 3.0.0
3. Added `include ":library"` to settings.gradle file
4. Edited *build.gradle(Module:CordovaLib)* file like this

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           google()
       }

       dependencies {
          implementation project(':library')
       }
   }

   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
   apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
   apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

   group = 'org.apache.cordova'
   version = '6.3.0'
   ```
5. Edited *build.gradle(Module:android)* file like this

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           google()
       }

      // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
      // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
      // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
      // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
       }
   }

   // Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
       }
    }
   ```

This are the files that have edited show in the folder structure

[image]

Though I'm just using android studio and cordova for the first time, I really want to make this work but haven't been able to fix this issue for the past couple of days. Need all the help I can get

Comment: Please include your code as plain text, not as images next time

Comment: @VadimKotov edit done, images have been removed and code added. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: I don't really know. Maybe someone will answer this